# android 3.0.1 ddms, device online but no apps (question marked instead)

Tags: ddms

In android studio 3.0.1./ddms, i see my device (huawey p9 lite, android 7.0 nougat online), but i cant see any apps. In logcat i see level, time, pid, tag, text columns but in application column i see just question marked.

- usb debugging enabled
- android studio updated, api level 24;
- file explorer listed

What i need to do to see running apps? [pictore of my ddms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRtne.png) i need to root my device? sry for noob question.